# prepend field to onepage checkout billing form

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template, onepage-checkout

The onepage layout's file `billing.phtml` offers the following entry point:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.onepage.billing.extra')?>
```

So I can hook into that and do:

```
<checkout_onepage_billing>
    <reference name='checkout.onepage.billing'>
        <block type='checkout/onepage_billing' name='checkout.onepage.billing.extra'
               template='billing_myform.phtml'></block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_billing>
```

I also found out that you can place blocks "wherever" you want with the before and after attribute.

```
<block type="core/template" name="my_block" before="not-sure-what-should-go-here-the-id?" template="billing_myform.phtml"/>
```

So is there a way to add my field to any place in the billing form?
Say right before the company input?